# What should we do when the new data drastically change the current model?

Tags: machine-learning, datasets, models, supervised-learning, explainable-ai

In machine learning (in particular, supervised learning), if some new data changes the previous model/function drastically, then I think we should study that data. Does it happen? How to handle such a situation?

Comment: Welcome to AI!  I've taken the liberty of adding the "ai-basics" and "models" tag.

Comment: I'd guess the new data has a different distribution then what the model has seen up to that point. So, distribution shift would be the first thing that'd come to my mind.